# aiohttp.ClientSession hangs without hitting timeout threshold

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My code is pretty similar to this:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

class Multiple_HTTP:
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch(session,url):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                status  =   response.status
                text    =   await response.text()
                return (url,status,text)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch_all(urls,timeout):
        loop            =   asyncio.get_event_loop()
        session_timeout =   aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None,sock_connect=timeout,sock_read=timeout)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop , timeout=session_timeout , connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as session:
            cwlist  =   [loop.create_task(Multiple_HTTP.fetch(session,url)) for url in urls]
            results =   []
            results =   await asyncio.gather(*cwlist,return_exceptions=True)
            return results
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def run(urls,timeout=5):
        return asyncio.run(Multiple_HTTP.fetch_all(urls,timeout))
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And, for some URLs, it hangs at `response.text()`

It does not honour the timeout, and the web renderizes alright on Chrome running on a Windows box.

Is there something wrong in my code?

How can I modify it for it to work (work as in raising a TimeOut Exception instead of just hanging, for example)?

Comment: Try using `connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False, limit=0)`. Maybe the requests are waiting for other requests to finish first.

Comment: If it might throw up some light, I've run this test for a single known offending URL and hangs as well

Comment: Can you share that URL, I'll test it locally to try finding out the reason first then reply back to you

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to search for a random url behaving like this. Here you wave: ```https://3.12.101.179/api/system/deviceinfo```

Comment: I tried and found out that it responded with `302` status, which redirects to the URL `https://3.12.101.179/welcome.htm` and that's the actual URL that make the `.text()` hangs. You can disable the redirection by adding `allow_redirects=False` on the request or try other way.